# how to push array elements on three arrays based on specific percentage and specific sequence in php?

Tags: php, laravel

**i'm trying to solve this problem:**

I've 3 percentage (%) stored in three callers: (Caller1, Caller2 and Caller3) like this:

```
$callers = [
    'Caller1' => 50,
    'Caller2' => 30,
    'Caller3' => 20
];
```

and I've ten `numbers` to call, i want to assign the numbers to each caller based on their percentage.

**Example:**

if numbers are (1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8,9,10), then the calls should be split like the bellow **sequence** based on their percentage (Note: like the below sequence):

- Caller1:  1,4,7,9,10
- Caller2:  2,5,8
- Caller3:  3,6

**my code like this:**

```
class MyClassName
{
    // Each caller with their call percentage
    private $callers = [
        'caller1' => 50,
        'caller2' => 30,
        'caller3' => 20
    ];

    public $caller1 = array();
    public $caller2 = array();
    public $caller3 = array();

    public function splitCalls(array $numbers)
    {
        //count numbers
        //get spesific number of each percentage
        //loop on numbers and push numbers into 3 arrays based on percentage
        $count = count($numbers);
        $callerOneNumbers = floor(($this->callers['caller1'] / 100) * $count);
        $callerTwoNumbers = floor(($this->callers['caller2'] / 100) * $count);
        $callerThreeNumbers = floor(($this->callers['caller3'] / 100) * $count);  

        for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
            if (count($this->caller1) < $callerOneNumbers) {
                array_push($this->caller1, $numbers[$i]);
                $i++;
            }

            if (count($this->caller2) < $callerTwoNumbers) {
                array_push($this->caller2, $numbers[$i]);
                $i++;
            }

            if (count($this->caller3) < $callerThreeNumbers) {
                array_push($this->caller3, $numbers[$i]);
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
}

$obj = new MyClassName;
$split = $obj->splitCalls([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9,10]);
var_dump($obj->caller1);
var_dump($obj->caller2);
var_dump($obj->caller3);
```

**my result like this:**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 5
  2 => int 9
C:\wamp64\www\test.php:102:
array (size=3)
  0 => int 2
  1 => int 6
  2 => int 10
C:\wamp64\www\test.php:103:
array (size=2)
  0 => int 3
  1 => int 7
```

**but i want like this:**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 4
  2 => int 7
  3 => int 9
  4 => int 10


array (size=2)
  0 => int 2
  1 => int 5
  2 => int 8


array (size=1)
  0 => int 3
  1 => int 6
```

any help please

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with your code is that at ever loop, you have `$i++` (in the `for()` loop).  This skips 1 array entry per loop (4 and 8 in this example).  So a simple solution to your problem would be to change the loop to...

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count;) {
```

as highlighted in the comments, this can cause a problem if the split doesn't give a nice round split. Changing to using `round` instead of `floor` will solve this, although the split can seem unbalanced.

e.g with 50, 30, 20 split, 2 items will give [[1], [2], []].  If this is OK, then follow this method.

Comment: Wow; I was today years old when I learned that you don't need the 3rd parameter of a `for()` loop. Just have to make sure that all logic branches include some kind of `$i++`, otherwise you _might_ end up in an infinite loop (i.e. in [this example](https://3v4l.org/2o04v) vs [this one](https://3v4l.org/V4sOg))

Comment: This solution will also lead to an infinite loop in some cases (like [the case](https://3v4l.org/bhNJU) where `count($numbers) == 2` or 5 ...). It can be solved using `round()` instead of `floor()` [like here](https://3v4l.org/OG25q)

Comment: @N69S, there is a general issue with any problem like this.  How do you deal with 2 items when you must split the result in 50, 30, 20% groups.  What is the correct answer - is there a correct way of splitting it?  Infinite loops aren't the solution, I would agree though.

Comment: @NigelRen there is an intuitive solution, and the infinite loop issue exits for not only 2 items, but also 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 21... and so on.

Comment: @N69S, I've updated the answer - although still not sure about 2 items as this gives a 50,50,0%age split.

Answer (score 1):

You can be flexible with any amount by calculating a distribution array. Then you know how many items need to go in there and can sequential iterate through it.

```
$distribute = function(array $callers, array $data): array {
    $distribution = array_values(array_map(fn($percentage) => (int) $percentage/100 * count($data), $callers));
    $results = [];
    $index = 0;
    $length = count($callers);
    foreach ($data as $value) {
        $added = false;
        while (!$added) {
            $row = $index % $length;
            if ($distribution[$row] > 0) {
                $results[$row][] = $value;
                $distribution[$row]--;
                $added = true;
            }
            $index++;
        }
    }

    return array_combine(array_keys($callers), $results);
};

echo json_encode($distribute(['Caller1' => 50, 'Caller2' => 30, 'Caller3' => 20], range(1,10)));
```

#### Output

JSON encoded for nicer display.

```
{"Caller1":[1,4,7,9,10],"Caller2":[2,5,8],"Caller3":[3,6]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I support @MarkusZeller's coding intention to have a "distribution" array.  Here is my implementation of the same technique.  My snippet converts percentage values into integers. Then while looping the integers will be decremented while also consuming the "numbers" array.

The following approach does not break when the total percentage is something other than 100%.  It will endeavor to distribute all numbers and to do so fairly.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aYnTG))

```
function splitCallers($callers, $numbers) {
    $count = count($numbers);
    $limits = array_map(
        fn($v) => (int) $count * $v / 100,
        $callers
    );

    $result = [];
    while ($limits && $numbers) {
        foreach ($limits as $caller => &$limit) {
            if (!$limit) {
                unset($limits[$caller]);
                continue;
            }
            if (!$numbers) {
                break;
            }
            --$limit;
            $result[$caller][] = array_shift($numbers);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
var_export(splitCallers($callers, range(1, 10)));
```